# How to tell if Google Analytics is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I make a lot of javascript widgets.  As part of these widgets, we often use Google Analytics to track actions within the widget.  Simplified, what I do is:

```
var setupGA = function(){ window._gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-###']); };
if(window._gaq){
    setupGA();
} else {
    this.loadScript(GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_PATH, function(){
      var waitga = setInterval(function(){
          if(window._gaq){
              clearInterval(waitga);
              setupGA();     
          }
      }, 500);
    });
}
```

Where GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_PATH is my local path to the file and loadScript is a custom method to load the script and execute a callback.

With Google updating their analytics library (now analytics.js), old methods of ensuring that the analytics library has been loaded no longer work.  The [example code for google analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) helpfully provides a global ga object, but this object can have a custom name.  With the old queue to check, I'm wondering how best I can check for the existance of either analytic.js or ga.js versions of google analytics (I Can skip the very old Urchin Tracking types).

It must be something like:

```
var setupGA = function(){ window._gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-###']); };
if(window._gaq && !window.**ga**){
    setupGA();
} else {
    this.loadScript(GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_PATH, function(){
      var waitga = setInterval(function(){
          //_gaq will always be loaded for now
          if(window._gaq){
              clearInterval(waitga);
              setupGA();     
          }
      }, 500);
    });
}
```

Where the **ga** is whatever global element I can check.  I suppose thats what I'm looking for

Comment: I literally JUST did this this morning for a couple of little gadgets I made.  I just copied the exact same Analytics code I use on the rest of my site into the .js file.  Analytics reports activity on whatever page the Gadget shows up on, even on outside domains.  Does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to track usage stats for your widget while it's running on other people's sites?

Comment: Reporting isn't a problem as much as checking if analytics is loaded.  If my client loads analytics.js and I check for window.gaq, I wont find it and will make an extra request for the other version.  It's not as simple as checking for ga because the client can (and does) name the google analytics object to whatever they want.

Comment: Yes, I am tracking my widget in use on other sites.  The code above is somewhat simplified and I always namespace my tracking.    This hasn't been a problem in the past (ga.js), but with more of my clients using the newer version (analytics.js) and being unable to detect that it's loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered my own question with a little more exploration.

With the new Universal Analytics platform, it seems that a window level variable is created.  That  variable is called **GoogleAnalyticsObject**.  This object will give you the variable name created to house the Universal Analytics Object

```
EX:  Using (window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga'); will return "ga"
EX:  Using (window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','notGA');  will return "notGA"
```

You can then use this variable to pull the Analytics object:

```
window[window.GoogleAnalyticsObject]
```

Comment: For what its worth, I hope this tracking is opt-in. If I found out someone was downloading additional scripts and making additional HTTP requests on my site without my knowledge I'd be pretty annoyed.

Comment: Note, the `GoogleAnalyticsObject` is not guaranteed to be there, so you should still check for `ga`. Also, your code should add quotes around "GoogleAnalyticsObject", or simply write `window.GoogleAnalyticsObject`. What you have now makes it look like a variable.

Comment: Excellent point Philip.  The additional tracking in this case is contractually accepted by our clients.    
  
Anecdotally, I have several clients who are using custom named analytics.js objects.  In each of those pages, I have access to the GoogleAnalyticsObject.  Since ga isn't a given either, I'll cautiously lean upon GoogleAnalyticsObject while also trying to detect _gaq/_gat.
  
I've edited the answer as you've suggested

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to open the browser console and look for the tracking request in the network tab.  If the tracking code isn't loading successfully, you won't see a tracking request being sent to Google.

With Universal Analytics (analytics.js), look for a request to www.google-analytics.com/collect

With Legacy code (ga.js or urchin.js), look for a request for __utm.gif

If your browser uses a script blocking plugin like NoScript, the tracking code won't run unless you allow scripts from www.google-analytics.com